# Need to Implement Zend_Rest_Client for the following curl method

Tags: php, zend-framework, curl, zend-rest

I usually use curl to call rest api's like this

```
$user_data = array("userName" => "myuser@mydomain.com" ,"password" => "mydomain123" );
$data = json_encode($user_data);
$headers = array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json',);
$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://myursl.com/myapi/v1/Api.svc/something/someother');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($handle);
$code = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($handle);
print_r($response);
```

The above code is working fine with API and printing the expected response , When I do the same thing using Zend_Rest_client of Zend Framework

like this

```
$base_url = 'http://myursl.com/myapi/v1_0/Api.svc';
$endpoint = '/something/someother';
$user_data = array("userName" => "myuser@mydomain.com" ,"password" => "mydomain123" );
$client = new Zend_Rest_Client($base_url);
$response = $client->restPost($endpoint, $user_data);
```

I am getting 404 error like this

```
(Zend_Http_Response)#62 (5) { ["version":protected]=> string(3) "1.1" ["code":protected]=> int(404) ["message":protected]=> string(9) "Not Found"] }
```

Where actually I am wrong in implementing Zend Rest Client

Thanks in advance for responding to this post

Comment: Zend_Rest is deprecated and will removed in favor of Zend\Http in ZF2. Can you try to do the same with Zend_Http?

Comment: I am not in a position to upgrade my web application now to ZF2 , its been done in ZF1.10 Please suggest any solution in ZF 1.10

Comment: I suggest you not build new stuff over deprecated components. However your base_url differs from CURL to Zend_Rest

Comment: Ohh thats just an example , Since its a typo I will edit this really sorry for confusion

Comment: Ohh bot use the same URL please ignore the typo there @Maks3w

Answer (score 0):

Although it might not be the finest solution I finally ended up inheriting Zend_Rest_Client and overriding _performPost() like this:

```
class My_Rest_Client extends Zend_Rest_Client {
    protected function _performPost($method, $data = null)
    {
        $client = self::getHttpClient();
        if (is_string($data)) {
            $client->setRawData($data, 'application/json');
        } elseif (is_array($data) || is_object($data)) {
            $client->setParameterPost((array) $data);
        }
        return $client->request($method);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
$rest = new My_Rest_Client('http://my.rest.url');
$rest->restPost('post-path', $data);
```